# how to send two different sizes of lists into excel using java

Tags: java, excel

HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet=workbook.createSheet("Demo_Sheet");

```
        // Creating Row Heading
        HSSFRow rowheading=sheet.createRow(0);

        rowheading.createCell(0).setCellValue("INNER CLASS");
        rowheading.createCell(1).setCellValue("INNER METHOD");

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            HSSFCellStyle cellheaderstyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            HSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
            font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
            font.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
            font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)11);
            cellheaderstyle.setFont(font);
            cellheaderstyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
            rowheading.getCell(i).setCellStyle(cellheaderstyle);

        }
        List<String> list1=DemoOnInnerMethod2.getInnerClasses();
        List<String> list2 = DemoOnInnerMethod2.getInnerMethods();

        for(int j=0;j<list1.size();j++)
        {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(j+1);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(list1.get(j));
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(list2.get(j));

        }FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/dilipp/Desktop/abcd.xls"));
        workbook.write(fout);
        fout.close();
        System.out.println("Success");
```

In above code there are two lists list1 and list2 with different sizes.list1 contains 4 elements and list2 contains 5 elements.But in excel sheet  I was getting only 4 elements for list1 and list2 as well.But I need 1st column of excel is list1 with 4 elements and 2nd column with list2 of 5 elements.
Please suggest to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once you exit the *for* loop, create a new row and add the 5th element from `list2` to the second column

```
for(int j=0;j<list1.size();j++)
{
    Row row = sheet.createRow(j+1);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(list1.get(j));
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(list2.get(j));
}
sheet.createRow(j+1);
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(list2.get(j));
```

If you want to do it within the loop itself, loop the larger list but adding a condition

```
for(int j=0;j<list2.size();j++)
{
    Row row = sheet.createRow(j+1);
    if (j < list1.size()) {
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(list1.get(j));
    }
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(list2.get(j));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another loop

```
for(int j=0;j<list1.size();j++)
{
    Row row = sheet.createRow(j+1);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(list1.get(j));

}


for(int j=0;j<list2.size();j++)
{
    Row row = null;
    (j >= list1.size()) {
        row = sheet.createRow(j+1);
    }else {
        row = sheet.getRow(j+1);
    }
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(list2.get(j));

}
```

There might be no grantee the list 2 is always fixed with one value being greater than list 1,hence the use of list :P

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't think you can call `createRow` twice passing the same row number.

Comment: @user7  Ohh I did not know that ill modify the answer

Comment: @user7 i took your if condition  logic :P

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be `j >= list1.size()`?